# Datatables does not retain the selected filter column values if the value has special characters

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using cascading datatables. It works fine. It appears, however, that if I select a value under Name or Office, the selected value is not retained in the dropdown menu. However, if I select Postion, it retains the selected value, for example: Director or System Architect.

It is because Columns 1 and 3 have special characters in the column values, which probably explains why it does this. (. - :) etc. Is there a way around this? Users are unable to tell which value was selected from the dropdown menu.Thanks.

https://live.datatables.net/suwopemu/1/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect( table );
  table.on( 'draw', function () {
    buildSelect( table );
  } );


});

function buildSelect( table ) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns( [0, 1, 2] ).every( function () {
    var column = table.column( this, {search: 'applied'} );
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
    .appendTo( $( '#dropdown' + counter ).empty() )
    .on( 'change', function () {
      var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
        $(this).val()
      );

      column
      .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
      .draw();
    } );

    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
      select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
    } );
    
    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if ( currSearch ) {
      select.val( currSearch.substring(1, currSearch.length-1) );
    }
  } );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: it's because you are rebuilding your select and not setting the selected value afterwards. It's not the same select, it's a new one. Store the value that you're filtering and then set selected on the option that matches.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure how to do it. Can you please give more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: I was wrong, I've worked out a solution for you and will post an answer.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to look into the Search Panes extension for datatables as it might end up giving your users a better experience and alleviate you from having to implement something from the ground up. You can see the documentation on the extension [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/) and a demo [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/initialisation/simple.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `column.search()` is returning a regex pattern to match. So I simply modified the

```
// The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
var currSearch = column.search();
if ( currSearch ) {
  select.val( currSearch.substring(1, currSearch.length-1) );
}
```

section to use regEx and find the value in the unique list

```
// The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
var currSearch = column.search();
if ( currSearch ) {
  select.val( column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))) );
}
```

Here is a working example of this in action

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });


});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<div class="searchbox">
  <p>Name: <span id="dropdown1">
    </span>
  </p>

  <p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
    </span>
  </p>

  <p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
    </span>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID.AI</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett -2</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```